# How to combine two query in one table

Tags: mysql, postgresql

> Is it possible to combine two query in one table? Just like the example below. And if its 0 or Null if no data. I want to make it my table like this:

| plan | actual | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 6 | 2021-01 |
| 15 | 10 | 2021-02 |
| 10 | 0 or Null | 2021-03 |
| 8 | 4 | 2021-05 |
| 10 | 6 | 2021-06 |

> Here's my sample query for PLAN :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PARTICIPANT_ID) AS PLAN,
(TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_START_DATETIME, 'YYYY-MM'))AS MONTH

FROM(
SELECT  
MIN(COALESCE(CSD.RESCHEDULED_START_DATETIME, CSD.SCHEDULED_START_DATETIME)) AS SCHEDULED_START_DATETIME, 
MAX(COALESCE(CSD.RESCHEDULED_END_DATETIME, CSD.SCHEDULED_END_DATETIME)) AS SCHEDULED_END_DATETIME,
CP.PARTICIPANT_ID, count(distinct participant_id)

FROM ERP.COURSE_PARTICIPANT AS CP

INNER JOIN ERP.COURSE_SCHEDULE_DETAIL AS CSD
ON CP.COURSE_SCHEDULE_ID = CSD.COURSE_SCHEDULE_ID
INNER JOIN ERP.COURSE_SCHEDULE AS CS
ON CSD.ID = CS.ID
INNER JOIN ERP.COURSE AS C
ON CS.COURSE_ID = C.ID
INNER JOIN ERP.COURSE_CATEGORY AS CC
ON C.COURSE_CATEGORY_ID = CC.ID
INNER JOIN ERP.EMPLOYEE AS E
ON CP.PARTICIPANT_ID = E.ID
INNER JOIN ERP.MEMBER_ROLE AS MR
ON E.MEMBER_ROLE_ID = MR.ID

WHERE C.MANDATORY = 'Yes'
AND MR.ROLE_TYPE = 'Dev'
AND CC.CATEGORY = 'Programmer'

GROUP BY CP.PARTICIPANT_ID) AS COURSE_PARTICIPANT

GROUP BY MONTH
```

| plan | month |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 2021-01 |
| 15 | 2021-02 |
| 10 | 2021-03 |
| 8 | 2021-05 |
| 10 | 2021-06 |

> This is my 2nd query for Actual:

```
TO_CHAR(LOG_IN_DATETIME, 'YYYY-MM') AS MONTH
FROM(
SELECT MAX(COALESCE(CA.LOG_IN_DATETIME, CA.LOG_OUT_DATETIME)) AS LOG_IN_DATETIME,
MAX(COALESCE(CA.LOG_OUT_DATETIME, CA.LOG_IN_DATETIME)) AS LOG_OUT_DATETIME,
CA.PARTICIPANT_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT C.NAME) AS COURSE
FROM ERP.COURSE_ATTENDANCE CA

INNER JOIN ERP.COURSE_SCHEDULE_DETAIL AS CSD
ON CA.COURSE_SCHEDULE_DETAIL_ID  = CSD.COURSE_SCHEDULE_ID
INNER JOIN ERP.COURSE_SCHEDULE AS CS
ON CSD.COURSE_SCHEDULE_ID = CS.ID 
INNER JOIN ERP.COURSE AS C
ON CS.COURSE_ID = C.ID
INNER JOIN ERP.COURSE_CATEGORY AS CC
ON C.COURSE_CATEGORY_ID = CC.ID
INNER JOIN ERP.EMPLOYEE AS E
ON CA.PARTICIPANT_ID = E.ID
INNER JOIN ERP.MEMBER_ROLE AS MR
ON E.MEMBER_ROLE_ID = MR.ID
WHERE CA.STATUS = 'P' 
AND C.MANDATORY = 'Yes' 
AND MR.ROLE_TYPE = 'Dev'
AND CC.CATEGORY = 'Programmer'
GROUP BY PARTICIPANT_ID
HAVING COUNT(C.NAME) >= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ERP.COURSE C
JOIN ERP.COURSE_CATEGORY CC
ON C.COURSE_CATEGORY_ID = CC.ID
WHERE CC.CATEGORY = 'Programmer')
)AS COURSE_ATTENDANCE
WHERE TO_CHAR(LOG_IN_DATETIME, 'YYYY-MM') BETWEEN '2021-01' AND '2021-12'
GROUP BY MONTH
```

| actual | month |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 2021-01 |
| 10 | 2021-02 |
| 0 | 2021-03 |
| 4 | 2021-05 |
| 6 | 2021-06 |

> I hope you will help me regarding to my query. Thank you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

query1 = (your query1);
query2 = (your query2);

select * from query1 INNER JOIN query2 on query2.month = query1.month;

Comment: a) queries in FROM must be enclosed with parenthesis, and aliases must be assigned to them; b) `month` is reserved word, it must be quoted with backticks; c) This query will return `month` column twice - use separate column list, or replace ON with USING.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.